# I want to refresh list view automatically

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to refresh list view automatically when any push notification get retrieved, that list view contains all push notification messages. I am able to get refresh with on click with a button but not automatically,
I am getting push notification with firebase.

This is my Main Activity code

package com.example.romil.mypushexample;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

import static java.security.AccessController.getContext;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NotificationAddedListener {


    ListView listView;
    UserSessionManager sessionManager;
    API realtrackerApi;
    ArrayList<GetNotificationListOutput> data;
    MyFirebaseMessagingService myFirebaseMessagingService;
    int listItemCount;
    Notification_Adapter adapter;
    boolean notificationStatus=false;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.notification_listView);
        sessionManager=new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        realtrackerApi=GlobalMethods.getRealtrackerAPI(this);

//        message=myFirebaseMessagingService.getMessage();
//        image=myFirebaseMessagingService.getImage();

        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Push_Notification.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.showNotification).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RetroCallForGettingNotificationList();
                listView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        findViewById(R.id.refreshNotification).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                RetroCallForGettingNotificationList2();
            }
        });

        if (getIntent().getExtras() != null) {

            for (String key : getIntent().getExtras().keySet()) {
                String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString(key);

                if (key.equals("AnotherActivity") && value.equals("True")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("value", value);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }

            }
        }
        subscribeToPushService();
    }

    private void subscribeToPushService() {
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news");

        Log.d("AndroidBash", "Subscribed");
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Subscribed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        String token = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();

        // Log and toast
        Log.d("AndroidBash", token);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, token, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void bindUI(ArrayList<GetNotificationListOutput> data){

        this.data=data;
        try{
            if(data!=null) {
                int listSize = data.size();
                adapter = new Notification_Adapter(this, R.layout.notification_list_item, data);
                listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                //listItemCount=listView.getCount();

            }
            //setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listView);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    public void refreshList(ArrayList<GetNotificationListOutput> listData){
        listItemCount=listView.getCount();
        int listSize=listData.size();
        if(listItemCount < listSize){
            GetNotificationListOutput obj=listData.get(listSize-1);
            data.add(obj);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        try{
            ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
            if (listAdapter == null)
                return;

            int desiredWidth = View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(listView.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
            int totalHeight = 0;
            View view = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
                view = listAdapter.getView(i, view, listView);
                if (i == 0)
                    view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(desiredWidth, ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                view.measure(desiredWidth, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED);
                totalHeight += view.getMeasuredHeight();
            }
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
            listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
    }

    public void RetroCallForGettingNotificationList(){
        try{
            if(GlobalMethods.isConnectedToInternet(getApplicationContext(),false)) {
                String token=sessionManager.getToken();

                Call<ArrayList<GetNotificationListOutput>> add_notification_outputCall= realtrackerApi.GetNotificationList(token);
                add_notification_outputCall.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<GetNotificationListOutput>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<GetNotificationListOutput>> call, Response<ArrayList<GetNotificationListOutput>> response) {
                        if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null){
                            bindUI(response.body());
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<GetNotificationListOutput>> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("Retro Error:","on failure");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Retro Error:",""+e);
        }
    }

    public void RetroCallForGettingNotificationList2(){
        try{
            if(GlobalMethods.isConnectedToInternet(getApplicationContext(),false)) {
                String token=sessionManager.getToken();

                Call<ArrayList<GetNotificationListOutput>> add_notification_outputCall= realtrackerApi.GetNotificationList(token);
                add_notification_outputCall.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<GetNotificationListOutput>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<GetNotificationListOutput>> call, Response<ArrayList<GetNotificationListOutput>> response) {
                        if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null){
                            refreshList(response.body());
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<GetNotificationListOutput>> call, Throwable t) {
                        Log.e("Retro Error:","on failure");
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Retro Error:",""+e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void notificationAdded(boolean val) {
RetroCallForGettingNotificationList2();
    }
}
```

This is my Firebase support Class,

```
package com.example.romil.mypushexample;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

/**
 * Created by romil on 22/4/17.
 */

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = "FCM Service";
    String message;
    String imageUri;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    String TrueOrFlase;
    API realtrackerApi;
    UserSessionManager sessionManager;
    MainActivity mActivity;

    NotificationAddedListener addedListener;

    public void getActivityObjetM(){
        addedListener.notificationAdded(true);
    }



    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {


        // TODO: Handle FCM messages here.
        // If the application is in the foreground handle both data and notification messages here.
        // Also if you intend on generating your own notifications as a result of a received FCM
        // message, here is where that should be initiated.
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        //Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
//        Log.i(TAG,remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        realtrackerApi=GlobalMethods.getRealtrackerAPI(this);
        sessionManager=new UserSessionManager(this);

        remoteMessage.getData();
        Log.i(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());

        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
            imageUri = remoteMessage.getData().get("image");
            bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUri);
            TrueOrFlase = remoteMessage.getData().get("AnotherActivity");
            sendNotification(message, bitmap, TrueOrFlase);
            getActivityObjetM();
        }

        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody, Bitmap image, String TrueOrFalse) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("AnotherActivity", TrueOrFalse);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setLargeIcon(image)/*Notification icon image*/
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.testimage1)
                .setContentTitle(messageBody)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                        .bigPicture(image))/*Notification with Image*/
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmapfromUrl(String imageUrl) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return bitmap;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use LocalBrodcast Manger to pass event to main activity and refresh listviw

Comment: I have tried it, not working

Comment: what happes? any logcat error?

Comment: Its working now, thanks. Actually I was trying without initiate it in onPause and onResume.